# Ajuda em script Javascript SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Tags: javascript, algoritmo

Boa noite, estou tendo problemas para fazer condições if/else if/else no javascript, no curso de js do codecademy funciona, mas quando tento fazer alguns algoritmos no sublime usando a condicional, da o erro descrito no titulo.

```
<script>
    var note1, note2, media;

        note1 = parseFloat(prompt("Informe a primeira nota"));
        note2 = parseFloat(prompt("Informe a segunda nota"));

        media = (note1 + note2) / 2;

        if (media >= 5.0) or (media <= 6.0){
            console.log("Você é um mau aluno");
        }
        else if (media >= 6.1) or (media <= 7.0) {
            console.log("Você é um aluno mediano");
        }
        else {
            console.log("Você é um excelente aluno");
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toda a condição no `if` deve estar dentro de parenteses.

É permitido usar vários parenteses dentro do `if`, desde que tenha um englobando tudo

Suas comparações estão erradas, algumas linguagens aceitam `or` e `and` mas no java script se usa `&&` para `and` e `||` para `or`

```
if ((media >= 5.0) || (media <= 6.0)){
//...
else if ((media >= 6.1) || (media <= 7.0)){
```